# How to redirect a user depending on what their input contains?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a education project that contains javascript that redirects a user to a specific webpage depending on their input like so;

```
function passWord(){
  var testV = 1;
  var pass1 = prompt('Enter First 3/4 Digits of Post Code...','');
  while (testV < 3) {
    if (!pass1)  history.go(0);
    if (pass1.toUpperCase() == "NE1") {
      window.open('eligible.html');
      break;
    } else if (pass1.toUpperCase() == "NE2") {
      window.open('eligible.html');
      break;
```

And I wish to change the script so that rather than the user specifically enter in "NE1" or "NE2" for example, they could enter in anything as long as it contained "NE1" or "NE2"

What would be a reasonable way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be with ES6's **[`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)** method:

```js
function passWord() {
  var testV = 1;
  var pass1 = prompt('Enter First 3/4 Digits of Post Code...', '');
  while (testV < 3) {
    if (!pass1)
      history.go(0);
    if (pass1.toUpperCase().includes("NE1")) {
      window.open('eligible.html');
      break;
    } else if (pass1.toUpperCase().includes("NE2")) {
      window.open('eligible.html');
      break;
    }
  }
}

passWord();
```

You could also make use of a regex, or just `.indexOf()` in ES5 JavaScript:

```js
function passWord() {
  var testV = 1;
  var pass1 = prompt('Enter First 3/4 Digits of Post Code...', '');
  while (testV < 3) {
    if (!pass1)
      history.go(0);
    if (pass1.toUpperCase().indexOf("NE1") !== -1) {
      window.open('eligible.html');
      break;
    } else if (pass1.toUpperCase().indexOf("NE2") !== -1) {
      window.open('eligible.html');
      break;
    }
  }
}

passWord();
```